# Getting an 'html' type instead of 'image' from the browser

Tags: php, javascript, curl

I'm using CURL to fetch an image file from our server. After checking the browser's developer tools, it says that the returned type is 'html' instead of 'image'.

Here's the response:

```
/f/gc.php?f=http://www.norbert.com/get/image/BTS-005-00.jpg
GET 200 text/html   484.42 KB   1.68 s  <img>
```

Here's the CURL script:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$strUrl = $strFile;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $strUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $output;
```

Any additional specific code that I could add in my CURL script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP script is doing a cURL and returning the output without specific header of image.

So, by default, the browser will retrieve the data as HTML content.

Try to add a more specific header before returning the output.

Try

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
```

to specify to the browser the type of content your script is actually sending.

If you want the user to be able to download as file, you can also add the header:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '";');
```

If you are sending binary content, you could add:

```
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

Comment: I added header('Content-Type: image/jpg'); and it worked! Thanks!